# I can't get three LED lights to turn off and on in an order

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, led

I'm setting up 3 LED lights to turn on automatically in a specific order using a Raspberry Pi 3. I coded it with Python. At first I had two and it worked. Then, I added a third with the same program and it broke. Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO             ## Import GPIO Library
import time                         ## Import 'time' library (for 'sleep')

yellow = 17
green = 18
red = 22
## These are our LEDs
ourdelay = 0.1                      ## Delay
# pins 4,17,18,21,22,23,24,25

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)            ## Use BOARD pin numbering
GPIO.setup(yellow, GPIO.OUT)        ## set output
GPIO.setup(green, GPIO.OUT)
## function to save code

for num in range(1,100):
  print(num)
  GPIO.output(red, GPIO.HIGH )
  GPIO.output(yellow, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(green, GPIO.LOW)
  ## set HIGH (LED ON)
  time.sleep(ourdelay)                ## wait
  GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(yellow, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(green, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(ourdelay)                ## wait
  GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(yellow, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(green, GPIO.HIGH)
  time.sleep(ourdelay)        ## wait


  ##activateLED(blue,ourdelay)

GPIO.cleanup()                      ## close down library
```

When I run it, it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/blink.py", line 19, in <module>
    GPIO.output(red, GPIO.HIGH )
RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT
```

I would put a picture of my breadboard but I don't know how

Comment: to add the picture edit your question and in the editor toolbar there is an icon of a picture click it and follow the prompts.

Comment: Thanks by the way I just don't know how to upload a picture to here. I had already seen the picture icon.

Comment: The screen prompts you for what to do.

Comment: Not an issue wrt the question but something to consider: per [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) *Use 4 spaces per indentation level.*

Comment: Isn't the error pretty obvious? "The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT" - and if you check, you set yellow and green to output mode, but not red!

Comment: also correct this as well GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) is not for Board pin numbering Check it once GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)--- correct one.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the pin as an output before you use it.

To do that add the following line:

```
GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT)
```

below the matching lines for green and yellow:

```
GPIO.setup(yellow, GPIO.OUT)        ## set output
GPIO.setup(green, GPIO.OUT)
```